# Location of the test results and coverage file in VSO

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sonarqube-scan

I have a project build on .NET Core 2.2 and I'm using VSO build definition for Build & Release; with Sonar Qube for code quality.

The problem that I am facing is related to the location where the Visual Studio Test (Version 2.0) steps keep the test results, along with the code coverage. It seems that by default the test results (*.trx and *.coverage) files are being kept at D:\a\_temp.....*.trx location.

I particularly don't have an issue with this but it seems that Sonar Qube to failing to find the test results since it's looking under D:\a\1\TestResults

I have tried passing an extra vsconsole test parameter - `/Framework:.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2 /ResultsDirectory:$(agent.BuildDirectory)\TestResults` On doing the test results are being kept at D:\a\1, so Sonar Qube is able to get the test files but on doing that it seems that the Visual Studio Test step is unable to publish the Test Results and is failing.

Any ideas about this issue?

Comment: Can you share your build definition?